# Как вывести нормально ответ сервера который приходит в html android?

Tags: android, html

У меня в приложении есть сообщения, для того что-бы заполнить view элементы на экране показа сообщения, я вытаскиваю из ответа сервера, нужные мне поля, но вот тело сообщения выводится не очень красиво, там есть теги html которые я хотел-бы убрать. Вот пример как у меня выглядит сообщение:

[image: картинка].

А вот как я заполняю элементы экрана:

```
 public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ViewMessage> call, @NonNull Response<ViewMessage> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful())
                {

              tvPerson.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getName());
                    tvTheme.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getSubject());
                    tvBody.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getBody());
                    tvDate.setText(Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getDate());
                } else {
                    ResponseBody errorBody = response.errorBody();
                    try {
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(errorBody).string().contains("access_token_expired")) {
                            updateToken();
                        } else if (errorBody.string().contains("invalid_token")) {
                            logOut();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

я пробовал так удалить все ненужные теги:

```
String from = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).getName();
from.replaceAll("<br>","");
```

но это не помогло, теги все-равно остались. Если нельзя удалить из body сообщения теги, то может можно как-то вывести тело сообщения как html страницу, что-бы в итоге body показывало все сообщение как на сайте с учетом тегов. Возможно кто-то уже сталкивался с подобной ситуацией и сможет посоветовать мне решение моей проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот функция позволяющая убрать все html тэги

```
public String stripHtml(String html) {
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
   return Html.fromHtml(html, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
} else {
   return Html.fromHtml(html);
}}
```